# In Javascript determine if default email client will open a browser window or external program

Tags: javascript, mailto

Currently I have a simple mailto link that opens a user's default mail program; at the same time a modal appears on my user interface so that when the user returns they can select if they sent the email or not. However if the default email program is web based; like gmail; it will navigate the browser to gmail and the modal will never be visible. Worse than that they are navigated away from my site entirely. Setting _blank as the target would fix this issue for those people who have this type of default email client; but for others with Apple Mail or other standalone programs it opens a new tab.

I know I won't be able to determine what client they have; but it would be great to know what style client is about to open.

Comment: You can’t know this. Why force them to send an email thru their client? Can’t your system do that work?

Comment: This is a case where your process itself is the actual problem. You might just need to rethink your process and maybe use a server side system that sends the mail via a contact form or something.

Comment: Thanks. We have discussed that and may go that direction. The reasons we send the email through their email client is because they are already in communication with their client (person); opening in their email client allows them to continue their communication with that client easily; additionally the chance that the email goes to spam is reduced almost completely. Compared to that of an email generated from a server side process.